# Command failed: query utxo Error: This query cannot be used for the Byron era

Tags: wallet

When I am trying below command.

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

I am getting this error.

```
Command failed: query utxo  Error: This query cannot be used for the Byron era
```

What I have to do now?

Comment: What are the contents of the `payment.addr`? Does it contain a Byron or a Shelley address?

Comment: `$(cat payment.addr)
zsh: command not found: addr_test1vp465rg9nm7x3th67nfsccuav25ffvjk3wr5upk57k3ec9gadwcjp
` This is what i am getting

Comment: How do i know whether it is a shelly or byron?

Comment: Ok, that is a Shelley era address. You might try adding `--shelley-mode` or `--cardano-mode` to the command line.

Comment: `cardano-cli: encodeFailure: local state query: using acquire without a Point must be conditional on negotiating v8 of the node-to-client protocol
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Ouroboros/Network/Protocol/LocalStateQuery/Codec.hs:80:7 in ouroboros-network-0.1.0.0-a6337e1ec691134555c3c4cba8800a5d3d08f8812cda7fdf6590dc6bf33ac964:Ouroboros.Network.Protocol.LocalStateQuery.Codec%  ` I am getting this now after adding shelly-mode

Comment: Try `--cardano-mode` instead.

Comment: I am getting this error now `Command failed: query utxo  Error: This query cannot be used for the Byron era` for `--cardano-mode`

Comment: I got it working using cardano-mode but the wallet is showing me zer balance . `cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063 --cardano-mode`
`                           TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but i found these posts (https://forum.cardano.org/t/testnet-tutorial-querry-utxo-error/45249 + https://forum.cardano.org/t/command-failed-query-utxo-error-this-query-cannot-be-used-for-the-byron-era/55606) with basically the same instruction: Just wait till the node is fully synced !. I did that, and 1 hour later the query command passed.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It can take 6hr to 2days for node to sync. So don't panic wait for an hour

You can monitor the progress of sync using this command

`cardano-cli query tip --mainnet`

Check the `syncProgress` param in the generated json